# heap corruption error; unable to release cv::Mat opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, merge

This code works fine till the last line. It saves the correct image on the disk but it shows a "memory leak" after going out of the function - heap corruption. I had read that Mat doesn't need to be explicitly released. In my case, it crashes both with releasing and w/o releasing. Please help.

```
void CannyEdgeDetectionFilter::applyFilter(Mat& mat, Mat& mixedBandsMat)
{
    //Mat mixedBandsMat;

    vector<Mat> bandWiseImages;
    split(mat, bandWiseImages);

    //! Evaluate numChannels to be filtered in the input image
    int numChannels = mat.channels();
    int type = mat.type();

    //! Multiplied by 8 to get bits from Bytes
    int singleChannelDepth = 8*mat.elemSize1();

    for (int i = 0; i < numChannels; i++)
    {
        Canny(bandWiseImages[i], bandWiseImages[i], m_LowerThreshold,
            m_UpperThreshold, m_Kernel.rows);
    }

    //! Creating filteredImgMat in order to set DataValues
    mixedBandsMat.create(mat.rows, mat.cols, mat.type());

    //! Unifying the channels back to the output image
    merge(bandWiseImages, mixedBandsMat);
#if 1
    //Release bandWiseImages Mat memory
    int bandWiseVecSize = bandWiseImages.size();
    for(int i = 0; i < bandWiseVecSize; i++)
        bandWiseImages[i].release();
    bandWiseImages.clear();
    //fromTo.clear();
#endif
    imwrite("D:\\testAfterCannyEdgeDetetionFilter.jpg", mixedBandsMat);
    mixedBandsMat.release();
}
```

Comment: how do you detect the heap corruption, what program are you using for that? just wondering...

Comment: Does it show a memory leak, or does it crash?

Comment: I am working on visual studio 2008. The code crashes on exiting the function.

Comment: the very last  mixedBandsMat.release(); looks suspicious. you passed in a ref to mixedBandsMat, are you using it after leaving the function ?

Comment: Please post the part where you display the image and then exit the app.

Comment: Use [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lagdas/archive/2008/06/24/debugging-heap-corruption-with-application-verifier-and-debugdiag.aspx) post to easily identify the cause.

Comment: Do you have to pass in `mixedBandsMat`?

Comment: did you try to remove both .release calls? `bandWiseImages[i].release();` as well as `mixedBandsMat.release();`?

Answer (score 1):

With this little information I can only give you some support but no real solution:

**1.)** I guess that you are using Win7. So please [visit Dr. Memory](http://www.drmemory.org/) and install it (with path added to the system variables). Then you can start you application using the following command: `drmemory.exe -no_follow_children C:\\the_path\\YourExecutable.exe argv[1] ... argv[n]`. The -no_follow_children is used to ignore other third-party-code. Run this command. Dr. Memory will write the result down to `C:\Users\NAMEHERE\AppData\Roaming\Dr. Memory\`. Take a look, perhaps you now have a hint. If not -> post it here. =)

**2.)** OpenCV can sometimes crash when you are writing an image without compression-parameter. I've experienced this some time so I always give a vector of int-parameters to the imwrite-function:

```
vector<int> crparam;
crparam.push_back(CV_IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION);
cv::imwrite("D:\\testAfterCannyEdgeDetetionFilter.png", mixedBandsMat, crparam);
```

Comment: 3.) NO pointers, NO NO NO! (you'd be thrashing the internal refcounts this way).   guy there already has enough corruption trouble

Comment: Ok - Perhaps to much for now.

Comment: Guys, the crash happens when I diplay the image(fine) and then press Space to exit(immediately after that). Also the same project runs correctly previously 1 week ago, but now it simply crashes (same file from backup). Is it due to the computer? I'm using Wins 8 now.

Comment: I found no note telling me that Win8 is incompatible. But that doesn't mean it is. Could you post the Main plz?

Answer (score -2):

I couldn't find vector[i].release member function in STL for C++. Try vector[i].erase

Comment: it's all Mats that get released there, not vector